# Space explosion when folding over Producers/Parsers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memory, stream, reduce, haskell-pipes

Supposing I have a module like this:

```
module Explosion where

import Pipes.Parse (foldAll, Parser, Producer)
import Pipes.ByteString (ByteString, fromLazy)
import Pipes.Aeson (DecodingError)
import Pipes.Aeson.Unchecked (decoded)
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (pack)
import Lens.Family (view)
import Lens.Family.State.Strict (zoom)

produceString :: Producer ByteString IO ()
produceString = fromLazy $ pack $ intercalate " " $ map show [1..1000000]

produceInts :: 
    Producer Int IO (Either (DecodingError, Producer ByteString IO ()) ())
produceInts = view decoded produceString

produceInts' :: Producer Int IO ()
produceInts' = produceInts >> return ()

parseBiggest :: Parser ByteString IO Int
parseBiggest = zoom decoded (foldAll max 0 id)
```

The 'produceString' function is a bytestring producer, and I am concerned with folding a parse over it to produce some kind of result.

The following two programs show different ways of tackling the problem of finding the maximum value in the bytestring by parsing it as a series of JSON ints.

Program 1:

```
module Main where

import Explosion (produceInts')
import Pipes.Prelude (fold)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    biggest <- fold max 0 id produceInts'
    print $ show biggest
```

Program 2:

```
module Main where

import Explosion (parseBiggest, produceString)
import Pipes.Parse (evalStateT)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    biggest <- evalStateT parseBiggest produceString
    print $ show biggest
```

Unfortunately, both programs eat about 200MB of memory total when I profile them, a problem I'd hoped the use of streaming parsers would solve. The first program spends most of its time and memory (> 70%) in `(^.)` from Lens.Family, while the second spends it in `fmap`, called by `zoom` from Lens.Family.State.Strict. The usage graphs are below. Both programs spend about 70% of their time doing garbage collection.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the Prelude function `max` not strict enough? I can't tell if the library functions are bad, or if I'm using the library wrong! (It's probably the latter.)

For completeness, [here's a git repo](https://github.com/reuk/haskell-space-explosion) that you can clone and run `cabal install` in if you'd like to see what I'm talking about first-hand, and here's the memory usage of the two programs:

[image: memory usage of program 1]
[image: memory usage of program 2]

Comment: It looks like you make one large ByteString with `pack $ intercalate " " $ map show [1..1000000]` then `yield` it all at once, not incrementally create and yield the bytestring. I would investigate there first.

Comment: Sorry @Davorak, I don't think this is the problem. I've also encountered this kind of behaviour reading JSON objects from file. In that case there's no large data structure being created, but folding over the streamed objects still produces a space leak in the same way as the examples here. I'm especially confused, because looking at the implementation of `foldAll` from Pipes.Parse it seems to be strict, and the documentation for `fold` from Pipes.Prelude says that it's also strict.

Comment: @immutablestate How are you reading the JSON objects from file? Do you use `fromHandle` or `stdin` from `pipes-bytestring`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping a strict bytestring in a single `yield` doesn't make it lazy.  You have to yield smaller chunks to get any streaming behavior.

Edit:  I found the error.  `pipes-aeson` internally uses a `consecutively` function defined like this:

```
consecutively parser = step where
    step p0 = do
      (mr, p1) <- lift $
         S.runStateT atEndOfBytes (p0 >-> PB.dropWhile B.isSpaceWord8)
      case mr of
         Just r  -> return (Right r)
         Nothing -> do
            (ea, p2) <- lift (S.runStateT parser p1)
            case ea of
               Left  e -> return (Left (e, p2))
               Right a -> yield a >> step p2
```

The problematic line is the one with `PB.dropWhile`.  This adds a quadratic blow up proportional to the number of parsed elements.

What happens is that the pipe that is threaded through this computation accumulates a new `cat` pipe downstream of it after each parse.  So after N parses you get N `cat` pipes, which adds O(N) overhead to each parsed element.

I've created [a Github issue](https://github.com/k0001/pipes-aeson/issues/10) to fix this.  `pipes-aeson` is maintained by Renzo and he has fixed this issue before.

Edit: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/reuk/haskell-space-explosion/pull/1#issuecomment-44111058) to fix a second problem (you needed to use the `intercalate` for lazy bytestrings).  Now the program runs in 5 KB constant space for both versions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've updated the question so that it uses fromLazy instead (I think this yields smaller chunks). The memory usage is still far higher than I'd expect though.

Comment: @immutablestate I also found one last issue you need to fix to remove quadratic time complexity.  See my [pull request](https://github.com/reuk/haskell-space-explosion/pull/1) which contains the fix and heap profiles.  Long story short: you needed to use the `intercalate` for lazy bytestrings.